# ERROR: Error invoking `cargo metadata` when trying to compile INK! 4.0 smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo, toml

When I compile a specific INK! 4.0 smart contract i get the following error:
`` ERROR: Error invoking `cargo metadata ``

I have multiple INK! 4.0 smart contracts that are compiling successfully without the above error, i even copy and pasted the Cargo.toml file of the working contracts but Im still getting the above error.

Here's how my Cargo.toml file looks like:

[image]

Link - https://ibb.co/wdN3FTp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what's the reason but this specific error can be omit by using `# ink = { version = "4.0.0-beta", default-features = false }` instead `ink = { version = "https://github.com/paritytech/ink", commit = "4655a8b4413cb50cbc38d1b7c173ad426ab06cde", default-features = false }`

Comment: instead of branch in openbrush dependency you can use tag="3.0.0-beta", also scale dependency should be 2.3, and try to remove target and `Cargo.lock`, clean build the contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest ink i.e. 4.0.0-beta and latest openbrush, then you have to change little bit in Cargo.toml file.

1. use this for ink package:  `ink = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/ink", rev = "4655a8b4413cb50cbc38d1b7c173ad426ab06cde", default-features = false }`
2. use version = "2.3" for scale_info: `scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }`
3. for openbrush use tag instead version: `openbrush = { tag = "3.0.0-beta", git = "https://github.com/727-Ventures/openbrush-contracts", default-features = false, features = ["psp34"] }`

Comment: Hi @Ganesh11 I am tried all the changing in toml file but code is not working yet.